# MSBuild: How to read Assembly Version and FIle Version from AssmeblyInfo.cs?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, assemblyversions

Using MSBuild script how can we get AssmeblyVersion and FileVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Using MSBuild script how can we get AssmeblyVersion and FileVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs?

To get the `AssmeblyVersion` via MSBuild, you can use [GetAssemblyIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296.aspx) Task.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project, just before the end-tag `</Project>`, place below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="GetAssmeblyVersion" AfterTargets="Build">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity
        AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Assemblies"
          ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>

    <Message Text="Assmebly Version: %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version)"/>
  </Target>
```

To get the `FileVersion`, you could add a custom [MSBuild Inline Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd722601.aspx) to get this, edit your project file `.csproj`, add following code:

```
  <UsingTask
TaskName="GetFileVersion"
TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">

    <ParameterGroup>
      <AssemblyPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
      <Version ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Using Namespace="System.Diagnostics" />
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
      Log.LogMessage("Getting version details of assembly at: " + this.AssemblyPath, MessageImportance.High);

      this.Version = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(this.AssemblyPath).FileVersion;  
    ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>



  <Target Name="GetFileVersion" AfterTargets="Build">

  <GetFileVersion AssemblyPath="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Version" PropertyName="MyAssemblyFileVersion" />
  </GetFileVersion>
  <Message Text="File version is $(MyAssemblyFileVersion)" />
  </Target>
```

After with those two targets, you will get the `AssmeblyVersion` and `FileVersion` from `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

[image]

Note:If you want to get the version of a specific dll, you can change the `AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)"` to the:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MyAssemblies>somedll\the.dll</MyAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

AssemblyFiles="@(MyAssemblies)"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: for dotnet core and above, use `RoslynCodeTaskFactory` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74126512/error-msb4801-the-task-factory-codetaskfactory-is-not-supported-on-the-net-c

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2022