# How do I get just the Major part of version inside AfterBuild target

Tags: c#, msbuild

How do I get just the `Major` part of the version in AfterBuild target?  I thought I could access the property like shown below, but it just echoes the statement rather than show version.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity
        AssemblyFiles="$(MyAssemblies)">
      <Output
          TaskParameter="Assemblies"
          ItemName="MyAssemblyIdentities"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>

    <Message Text="Files: %(MyAssemblyIdentities.Version.Major)"/>
  </Target>
```

Here is the working code in Program.cs

```
 var version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format("My Application Version {0}", version.Major));
```

Comment: are you trying to get the version for the assembly you just tried to compile?

Comment: I just want part of the version (Major) from within the AfterBuild target

Comment: ok... your question says that... but which assembly do you want it from.

Comment: oh, sorry. yes the current assembly that I just compiled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624054/msbuild-how-to-read-assembly-version-and-file-version-from-assmeblyinfo-cs here's a starting point. i think the value is a string and you can do string manip on that.