# Get version from reference dll and set the same for current project

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, csproj

It is possible to implement in .csproj to during building get Version from reference .dll and set the same version for this project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>After create .dll from this project it should return 1.0.2.0 from firstProject</Version>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="firstProject, Version=1.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
    <HintPath>path\firstProject.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a `Directory.Build.props` file that contains the version? This way all projects use the version from this file until a project defines its own version.

For more information about the Direcotry.Build.props file, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2022

Comment: This is a bit more complex because I share some interface to another team in the form of a .dll and then it loads the .dll generated by them. And such a solution will not be very practical for my needs.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627234/18307736