# Error MSB4801: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-6.0

I have a UsingTask in my project, .Net 6.
I have a small script to set the AssemblyVersion, using CodeTaskFactory. See code below.
However, I cannot use or execute CodeTaskFactory on the build server using MS Build.

It gives these errors:

```
Error MSB4801: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild
Error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll". The task factory must return a value for the "TaskType" property
```

I looked at some other options, which all failed as they lacked one or another thing. So finally I ask here, what are my options to run a UsingTask with an output on the MS Build server?

My code

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="mytask"    
      TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
      AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <AssemblyVersion ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
          Log.LogMessage(MessageImportance.High, "we are here");
          AssemblyVersion = "1.2.3.4";
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
```

Answer (score 16):

The error message is correct. Your `UsingTask` is trying to use .Net Framework which is not available. Update the `UsingTask` to use the `RoslynCodeTaskFactory` in place of the `CodeTaskFactory`.

e.g.:

```xml
<UsingTask
    TaskName="mytask"
    TaskFactory="RoslynCodeTaskFactory"
    AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll" >
```

See [MSBuild inline tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-inline-tasks?view=vs-2022) which states (with emphasis added by me):

> In MSBuild 15.8, the RoslynCodeTaskFactory was added which can create
> .NET Standard cross-platform inline tasks. **If you need to use inline
> tasks on .NET Core, you must use the RoslynCodeTaskFactory.**

See also [MSBuild inline tasks with RoslynCodeTaskFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2022).